# disable session for static resources in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, session

I am using Sql server for session management in my website.

I found that when i load the page there are almost 45 update queries to the sql server session database. All of them are same (to update session expiry date).

I think this behaviour is because of total requests per page that includes css,js,images etc.

Is it possible that session module is not executed for static resources and it executes only once per asp.net page ?

Comment: I am in the middle of writing a custom session provider, and am seeing the exact same thing.  Every static resource on the page (images, css, etc.) causes another database query to update the session expiration date.